# Track custom tags in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I want to send to Analytics all the tags associated to my blog posts, and see a report in Analytics with the performance of each post tagged with a specific tag.

I want to be able to send multiple tags for one single page.

I tried with custom dimensions, but I believe that I can't assign multiple values for each dimension in one shot.

Thanks

Comment: You can concatenate the tags into a string, and then send that string into the CD.

Comment: How can I achieve this? Encoding them with json? Do you have an example? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It´s possilbe to send custom dimensions (or metrics) as a string, this looks like this:

```
ga('set', {'dimension1': v1, 'dimension2': v2, 'dimension3': v3});
```